# Looping over derived classes using foreach in Java

Tags: java, foreach

I have a class Movies with derived classes Action, Comedy and Drama. I have an array of different movies called rentedMovies.

When I loop over the array using the simple for loop,

```
for(int i = 0; i < rentedMovies.lenght; i++){
  ..Do something..
}
```

The IntelliJ IDE suggests that I can change this loop to foreach.

```
for(Movie movie: rentedMovies){
 ..Do something..
}
```

But doesn't this imply that all my movie elements will be treated as objects of the Movie class rather than of derived classes?
Is that a wrong suggestion by the IDE or am I not thinking right? Thanks.

Comment: Depends. What is `rentedMovies` declared as? Also, see polymorphism.

Comment: So a class Rental has an instance variable of Movie. rentedMovies is an array of Rental objects

Comment: You can use `instanceof` to determine which type of subclass it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumption is already implied by the fact that rendedMovies is declared similar to

```
ArrayList<Movie> rentedMovies
```

so the most specific information you will be able to know about the objects contained inside the collection is that they are of type `Movie`. You are forced to do that in Java since a generic collection can have just a specific type. To be able to add all subclasses to the collection you must provide a common super class.

The type information is lost when you add your objects to the class. Eg:

```
Comedy comedy = new Comedy();
rentedMovies.add(comedy);
Comedy comedy2 = rentedMovies.get(0); // compile error: get returns Movie
Movie movie = rentedMovie.get(0); // correct
```

In short, if you don't need the index of the current movie your snippets are equivalent. **Mind that the for-each statement works with iterators under the hood so if you are modifying the collection inside the loop then you must take care of what you are doing**.

If you want to obtain specific information of an element once retrieved from the collection then you must downcast it on your own (and forget compile type safety without hand checks) eg:

```
public Comedy asComedy() {
  return this instanceof Comedy ? (Comedy)this : null;
}
```

But if you need to do it then you should redesign the inheritance. Maybe you can move the behavior totally inside the subclasses of `Movie` so that you don't need to know the specific type but just invoke methods of the common interface.

Answer (score 1):

Your `rentedMovies` I assume is declared as `Movies[]` anyway so the original for loop will still have them as Movie objects.

If you want to use specific methods of the sub classes then you will have to cast in either case.

The advantage of using the implementation of `(int i = 0; i < rentedMovies.lenght; i++)` is that you have the index if you need to not loop the entired array (which then Intellij will not give you this warning) or index positions relative to the current Object

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array of different types then the type of the Array variable should be of a super-class.

Anyway if you are going to search for a specific type of a movie in the loop you must do explicit checking (not very good design).

So it really makes  no difference which loop you use... For each will be simpler and offer no disadvantages.

Answer (score 1):

The rentedMovies have to be the "Movie" class, if you have the "Action, Comedy and Drama" in one array. So if you iterate them through the for cycle, you iterate them like a "Movie", not like a "Action, Comedy or Drama".

The suggested IDE iteration is the same as you are using, but maybe a little more intuitive and can be used to a lot classes (like List), if you ever decide to change array to List.